# How to add data to MagicSuggest input via a button click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, magicsuggest

I am using [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html)
in a form. The plugin is working great but I want to have the functionality to add data to it via a button click.

This is what I have tried below, it adds the data to it but if I click on the input, the data disappears.

**HTML**

```
<div class="qa-suggested-profiles">
    <a href="#/" data-name="John Doe" class="btn btn-sm tag-profile-btn">Add this profile</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.qa-suggested-profiles').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var profileName = $(this).data('name');
    $('#tag-business .ms-sel-ctn').prepend('<div class="ms-sel-item ">' + profileName + '<span class="ms-close-btn"></span></div>');
    $('#tag-business .ms-sel-ctn input').attr('placeholder', '').width('auto');
    $('#tag-business .ms-sel-ctn div').prepend('<input type="hidden" value="1">');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something in the documentation which accomplishes this task. Go to http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html and search for `setValue([array] ids)` See example below:

```
var ms = $('#ms-setValue').magicSuggest({
  data: 'data.json'
});
ms.setValue([2, 3, 4]);
```

Here is the final code I used, I also added `removeFromSelection` to clear the selection on each button click

```
$('.qa-suggested-profiles').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var profileName = $(this).data('name');
    var ms = $('#tag-business').magicSuggest({
      data: '/data/business-profiles.json'
    });
    // remove current value
    ms.removeFromSelection(ms.getSelection(), true);
    // add selected value
    ms.setValue([profileName]);
});
```